# Zend framework modular application

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

How can we make a site with two section admin and user panel.

Zend Framework creates single session Zend_Auth for both panels. Which is creating problem in session handling like admin session goes to user panel vise versa.

My folder structure is:

- For user panel: **site/app/controllers**
- For admin: **site/app/admin/controllers**

Can any one tell me what is exact way to do this in Zend Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [session persistance](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.introduction.html#zend.auth.introduction.persistence.default). You'll have to use at least one custom namespace.